# How to store property file keys into variables in a shell script after reading them

Tags: shell, sh, properties-file

If I have a given property file and a shell script. How do I store each and every key-value pair in a different variable?

For example if I read the property file thing.properties that consists of:

```
USERNAME = "Me"
PASSWORD = "Secret"
DB_NAME = "THINGDB"
```

How do I store each of these keys in its own variable within the shell script labeled thingUSERNAME, thingPASSWORD etc. (Variable name can be anything as long is it contains some semblance of the file and the key)

(Note this must be done in an sh file)
Any input is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval`. Just be careful with this command though. It can be devastating. Unfortunately unlike `bash`, `sh` does not support `declare`.

```sh
$ cat property.txt
USERNAME = "Me"
PASSWORD = "Secret"
DB_NAME = "THINGDB"

$ cat shell.sh
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r line; do
    key="${line%% =*}"
    value="${line#*= }"
    eval "$key"="$value" # For ash, dash, sh.
    # declare "$key"="$value" # For bash, other shells.
done < property.txt

echo "username: $USERNAME"
echo "password: $PASSWORD"
echo "db_name: $DB_NAME"

$ ./shell.sh
username: Me
password: Secret
db_name: THINGDB
```

Comment: Don't use `eval`. `declare` will do the same thing, but (more) safely.

Comment: @chepner `sh` doesn't support that command though.

Comment: Actually, `declare` introduces its own problem: the quotes read from the file are treated as part of the value, not part of the assignment syntax.